# "CDO.Message" is not working in my Delphi application

Tags: delphi, installation, ole, cdo.message

I created an application uses

CreateOLEObject("CDO.Message")

Everything is working fine in my machine, but in another I got

Érvénytelen osztályú karakterlánc.

errormessage (hungarian).

This is meaning these error codes by ms support (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186063/hu):

-2147221005 (800401F3)

The destination machine is XP Prof with SP2.

I want to use CDO to send a message with SMTP.
What I need to install in this machine to I can send similarly as with my Win7 notebook (there is not Outlook)?

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to install [CDO 1.2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E17E7F31-079A-43A9-BFF2-0A110307611E&displaylang=en) to the destination machine?